# Can one remove the asavas without becoming an arahant?

Tags: the-buddha

Can one remove the asavas without becoming an arahant?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism.SE. What you have under the main question is not clear. We've put together some information to help you get started [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?).

Answer (score 3):

**Can you remove the asavas without becoming an arahant?**

I think that [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asava) suggests not:

> Rhys Davids & Stede (1921–25) state in part that "Freedom from the 'Āsavas' constitutes Arahantship."

And

> These points are collected and summarized by Bhikkhu Bodhi thus:
>
> > The āsavas or taints are a classification of defilements considered in their role of sustaining the forward movement of the process of birth and death.
> >
> > The three taints mentioned in the Nikāyas are respectively synonyms for craving for sensual pleasures, craving for existence, and ignorance. [The fourth āsava, attachment to views, appears in the commentaries.] When the disciple's mind is liberated from the taints by the completion of the path of arhantship, he reviews his newly won freedom and roars his lion's roar: "Birth is destroyed, the spiritual life has been lived, what had to be done has been done; there is no more coming back to any state of being."

There's another question about *asava* here: [What is effluent?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9414/254) The answer to that question is I think a good explanation, and it includes two references for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Arahant is a person who successfully removed the asavas. Thus, you cannot become an arahant without removing the asavas. You cannot remove the asavas by not removing the asavas.