# If the chain of dependent origination (Pratītyasamutpāda) ends, then isn't the last part independent?

Tags: theravada, pratityasamutpada

Dependent Origin or Pratītyasamutpāda is defined as

> It states that all dharmas (phenomena) arise in dependence upon other
> dharmas

And then there are these 12 causes one after another, each depending on the next one starting from Aging or decay, and death (Jarāmaraṇa) which depends on Birth, Rebirth (Jāti) and so on, which **finally ends in Ignorance, nescience (Avidyā).**

But notice Avidya seems to be not depending on anything. But as a rule all dharmas should be dependent on another dharma. How is this contradiction reconciled?

[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da)

Comment: This is a very good question. What does ignorance depend on? What is the condition for ignorance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cyclic dependency between ignorance and defilements (also called taints or fermentation).

> Ignorance originates from defilement. Ignorance ceases when defilement
> ceases.
> *Āsavasamudayā avijjāsamudayo, āsavanirodhā avijjānirodho*
>
> Defilement originates from ignorance. Defilement ceases when ignorance
> ceases.
> *Avijjāsamudayā āsavasamudayo, avijjānirodhā āsavanirodho*
>
> [MN 9](https://suttacentral.net/mn9/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Why is there such a cyclic dependency? This is amply discussed in "[Does MN9 imply a cyclic causation? How does it work?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25874/471)"

I quote from the best answer there:

> It is like being born in a poor uneducated family: because you are
> poor, you can't get education, and because you can't get education you
> are poor.

Comment: Excellent, just some small clarifications. Why is Defilement not present in the 12 dharmas listed in the chain. Is it the same as Sankhara or Samskara. What is the Sanskrit equivalent of Asava.

Comment: @MrGreenGold In Sanskrit, it's [Āsrava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asava).

Comment: thanks, but is Āsava same as Sankhara or equivalent to it, as Āsava is not present in the traditional chain of 12 causes.